# SetWindowsHookEx() WM_KEYBOARD_LL not coming through with full screen RDC

Tags: winapi, setwindowshookex

I'm trying to do a away timer style thing like Skype. If the user is 'away' for a period of time I'll trigger something. I have been using SetWindowsHookEx() with WM_KEYBOARD_LL which works fine. That is until you open a RDC connection and have it full screen. Then I never get the keyboard events.

Anyone come across this? Or know of a better way to achieve this? I have actually tested skype and with a full screen RDC it will correctly go from Away to Online if I type in the RDC.

Thanks

EDIT: After Raymond Chen's comment I did some testing, and he is right. Can not believe I never found this method after all my searching. It also solved an issue I was having with a WPF app not triggering the LL_Mouse/KEYBOARD events.

Thanks Again. Update my accepted answer based on this. The other answer is still good if you need to do LL_MOUSE/KWYBOARD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [`GetLastInputInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646302.aspx).  Try calling that periodically.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You'll not get keys pressed in remote desktop. I had this problem and only solution I found was this:

Using FindWindow API always look to find RDP window, if you've detected that full-screen RDP window has been created you should do this:

a) Unhook all hooks.
b) Reset all hooks.

So create a function which makes SetWindowHookEx API calls and call it SetHook and another one as UnHook function. Then re-call both of them anytime you find out user get into remote desktop.

Now you can get keys pressed even inside remote desktop connection.

I found my old code, I did something like this:

Created a timer with 1 sec.
Then

```
std::string tmp;
HWND hParent = ::FindWindow(TEXT("TSHELLHWND"), NULL);
GetWindowString(hParent, tmp);

ix = za.find(" - Remote Desktop");

if (hParent != NULL && ix != string::npos)
RestartHook();
```

You also should have a global variable to set when you've restarted hook, otherwise all the time it will restart the hook. When window closed, you can reset that global variable.

Comment: Yay thanks. That did work. Although I also found a slightly different way. I use EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND event with SetWinEventHook() to get notified of window cahnges and then use OpenInputDesktop() to see if the desktop has changed

Comment: great, that's also good trick. as I said that was my very old code and that days I found that way myself, I was tired of searching entire internet for it, no solution found. It backs to about 2006. But glad it still works and solved your problem.

Comment: Yeh, the biggest tip there was that you have to reset the hooks on the change of desktop. I had found nothing else telling me that! So thanks again.

Comment: This works only until *two* apps use this trick. Then they end up fighting with each other in order to be "first". The correct solution is GetLastInputInfo as noted in another answer.

Comment: That API doesn't return pressed key and also calling that API eventually like every 100 millisecond to capture user's input will exhause process memory and not a good idea

Comment: @VahidFarahmand Why would an API function leak memory every time it's called? I don't think that is the case. And that function isn't needed to get the pressed key, you still restart the hook as explained.