# WH_KEYBOARD_LL could not capture keyboard events when RDC is in full screen mode

Tags: c#

I am doing a c# window project that capture screen shot for each keyboard event on RDC.
  In this project i used WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook to catch keyboard event and
  Microsoft's RDC.

The problem is if remote session of remote machine already existed meaning that
  someone used that remote machine and disconnected without logging off,WH_KEYBOARD_LL
  hook could not catch keyboard events in full screen mode of RDC.

So images could not be captured.This problem happened on Microsoft server 2008 r2 64 bit.

I have search for this as much as i can. I could not still find out the solution.

Please, anybody help me for this problem.

Edit : I used Gma.Useractivity project from code project.

```
     In this project, following is the route given by Gma.Useractivty project to add custom event handler

     public static event KeyEventHandler KeyUp
     {
        add
        {
            EnsureSubscribedToGlobalKeyboardEvents();
            s_KeyUp += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            s_KeyUp -= value;
            TryUnsubscribeFromGlobalKeyboardEvents();
        }
      }


      private static void EnsureSubscribedToGlobalKeyboardEvents()
    {
        // install Keyboard hook only if it is not installed and must be installed
        if (s_KeyboardHookHandle == 0)
        {
            //See comment of this field. To avoid GC to clean it up.
            s_KeyboardDelegate = KeyboardHookProc;
            //install hook
            s_KeyboardHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(
                WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
                s_KeyboardDelegate,
                Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(
                    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]),
                0);
            //If SetWindowsHookEx fails.
            if (s_KeyboardHookHandle == 0)
            {

                //Returns the error code returned by the last unmanaged function called using platform invoke that has the DllImportAttribute.SetLastError flag set. 
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                //do cleanup


                //Initializes and throws a new instance of the Win32Exception class with the specified error. 
                throw new Exception("@@@ Gma.UserActivityMonitor >> HookeManager.Callbacks.cs [" + "Creating Keyboard Hook is fail] @@@");


            }                     
        }
    }


    I registered my keyboard event handler in the form load as following...
```

private void RDR9902_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        rdpProductionNode.FullScreenTitle = "????????(" + CommonData.userID + ")";
        WinAPI.SetWinFullScreen(this.Handle);

        HookManager.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(HookManager_KeyDown);
        HookManager.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(HookManager_KeyUp);
        HookManager.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(HookManager_MouseUp);
    }
```

Comment: If possible you should look at posting the relevant area of code so we can see what you've tried in context.

Comment: Full screen RDC also uses low level hooks. This is an unavoidable consequence of multiple applications installing hooks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SetWindowsHookEx() WM\_KEYBOARD\_LL not coming through with full screen RDC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596117/setwindowshookex-wm-keyboard-ll-not-coming-through-with-full-screen-rdc)